# Copy specific columns from multiple excel files in a folder "without opening the source files"

Tags: excel, vba

Source files in csv format are in Documents folder.

Path/Filename -

- Documents\SourceFile1.csv
- Documents\SourceFile2.csv
- Documents\SourceFile3.csv

Columns to be copied are -

- Column A
- Column C
- Column E

Destination file in xlsx format is in Documents folder.

Path/Filename -

- Documents\DestinationFile.xlsx

Requirement is to paste the columns copied from csv files to sheets in xlsx file.

- Columns copied from SourceFile1.csv to be pasted in Sheet1 of DestinationFile.xlsx
- Columns copied from SourceFile2.csv to be pasted in Sheet2 of DestinationFile.xlsx
- Columns copied from SourceFile3.csv to be pasted in Sheet3 of DestinationFile.xlsx

I tried this simple copy paste formula.

```
Sub CollectData()
Dim rgTarget As Range
Set rgTarget = ActiveSheet.Range(A:C)
rgTarget.FormulaArray = "='Documents\[DestinationFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!(A:A,C:C,E:E)"
rgTarget.Formula = rgTarget.Value
End Sub
```

This does not help me in copying columns from multiple files in one go.

Comment: Look into Powerquery

Comment: "without opening the source files" - there is no way for that with VBA. it can only read / edit open files.

Comment: I'm willing to try if there is a solution using Powerquery

Comment: Your way of extracting data can be adapted to be workable. But it has some obvious mistakes: Returning three **whole** columns using formulas will take extremely long time. So, you must restrict the columns number of rows of the existing ones. Being a csv file involved, it should not be so complicated. Then you do not need `FormulaArray`. `Formula` would be enough, but it does not work on **discontinuous** ranges. As logical approach, I do not think you really want extracting data from `DestinationFile`. I am a little busy now. If I will have some availability I can post an answer on this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It should do what you need, in the way you try. There also are some other methods, but I tried making it in the way you tried:

```
Sub TestCollectData()
  'extract Documents folder path:
  Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Dim strDocuments As String: strDocuments = objShell.NameSpace(&H5).Self.path & "\"
  Dim arrSources():  arrSources = Array("SourceFile1.csv", "SourceFile2.csv", "SourceFile3.csv") 'use here correct files name
  Dim arrSheets(): arrSheets = Array("SourceFile1", "SourceFile2", "SourceFile3") 'use here the correct sheets name
  
  'iterate between all existing source files:
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrSources)
    CollectData strDocuments, CStr(arrSources(i)), CStr(arrSheets(i)), i + 1
  Next i
End Sub

Sub CollectData(strFoldPath As String, csvName As String, strShName As String, shNo As Long)
  'determine the csv file number of rows
  Dim arrCSV, nrRows As Long
  arrCSV = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strFoldPath & csvName, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
  nrRows = UBound(arrCSV) + 1
  '____________________________________
  
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shNo)
  Dim rgTarget As Range: Set rgTarget = ws.Range("A1:E" & nrRows)
  With rgTarget
    .Formula = "='" & strFoldPath & "[" & csvName & "]" & strShName & "'!A1:E" & nrRows
     ws.Calculate 'calculate to update the formulas
    .value = .value 'transform formulas in values
    .Replace "#REF!", "", xlWhole 'the last row of csv file may be empty...
    .Range("B:B,D:D").EntireColumn.Delete 'delete the not necessary columns
  End With
End Sub
```

Of course, if the real path is not in system `Documents` folder, you should place your real folder path in `strDocuments` variable.

A faster, more reliable way would be the next:

```
Sub DirectCollectData()
  'extract Documents folder path:
  Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Dim strDocuments As String: strDocuments = objShell.NameSpace(&H5).Self.path & "\"
  Dim arrSources():  arrSources = Array("SourceFile1.csv", "SourceFile2.csv", "SourceFile3.csv")
  
  Dim arrAC 'Array for the three columns to be returned
  Dim sep As String 'the csv separator!!!
  sep = ","         'use here your csv files separator. Please, use the used one!!!
  
  Dim i As Long, k As Long, arrRow, arrCSV, nrRows As Long, ws As Worksheet
  For k = 0 To UBound(arrSources)
    arrCSV = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(strDocuments & arrSources(k), 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
    nrRows = UBound(arrCSV) + 1
    ReDim arrAC(1 To nrRows, 1 To 3)
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrCSV)
      arrRow = Split(arrCSV(i), sep)
      If UBound(arrRow) > 0 Then
          arrAC(i + 1, 1) = arrRow(0): arrAC(i + 1, 2) = arrRow(2): arrAC(i + 1, 3) = arrRow(4)
      End If
    Next i
    
    'set the sheet where to drop the collected data:
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(k + 1)
    
    'drop each array content, at once:
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrAC), 3).value = arrAC
    
    'autofit columns:
    ws.Range("A:A,B:B,C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    'clear the array for future use (ReDim):
    Erase arrAC
  Next k
End Sub
```

Please, try looking carefully to the code and update the **real** folder path where from the csv files to be used, the real csv files name (loaded in `arrSources`) and the real csv **separator**. The above code works as it is for comma (`,`) separator. It returns in the first three sheets of the **active workbook**.

An an ever better (faster) solution using `ADODB`:

```
Sub extractSliceSQL_() 'It works with closed workbook
'It needs a reference to 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library'
 'extract Documents folder path:
  Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Dim strDocuments As String: strDocuments = objShell.NameSpace(&H5).Self.path & "\"
  Dim arrSources():  arrSources = Array("SourceFile1.csv", "SourceFile2.csv", "SourceFile3.csv")
  
  Dim aRS As ADODB.Recordset, arrR(), i As Long, ws As Worksheet, strCols As String
  strCols = "[Col1],[Col3],[Col5] "  'when the columns to be returned headers as known
  'strCols = ""                       'when headers are not known (only the columns position)
  
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrSources)
    Set aRS = getData_(strDocuments, CStr(arrSources(i)), strCols)
    aRS.Open
        If strCols <> "" Then
            arrR = aRS.getRows()
        Else
            arrR = aRS.getRows(, , Array(aRS.fields(0).name, aRS.fields(2).name, aRS.fields(4).name))
        End If
    aRS.Close
    
    Set ws = Worksheets(i + 1)'set the sheet where to return
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrR, 2) + 1, 3).value = Application.Transpose(arrR)
    Erase arrR
  Next i

 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Public Function getData_(path As String, fileName As String, Optional strCols As String = "") As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cN As ADODB.Connection, RS As ADODB.Recordset
    Set cN = New ADODB.Connection: Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    cN.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                   "Data Source=" & path & ";" & _
                   "Extended Properties=""text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1;""")
    RS.ActiveConnection = cN
    If strCols = "" Then
        RS.Source = "select * from " & fileName 'it returns all columns
    Else
        RS.Source = "SELECT " & strCols & "FROM [" & fileName & "]" 'to return only A, C and E columns
    End If
    Set getData_ = RS
End Function
```

For the above solution **if the headers of the columns to be returned**! `Col1`, `Col3` and `Col5` in the above code (A, C, E columns) are known, they must be  placed in `strCols` variable. If not, `strCols = ""`.

The code can be adapted to not need the above mentioned reference (using Late binding), but it is a little faster using Early binding and it is good to have it, I think.

To automatically add the necessary reference, please run this piece of code firsly:

```
Private Sub addADODBRefFromFile()
  'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects  x.x Library`...
   On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\Ado\msado20.tlb"
    
    If Err.number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "The reference already exists..."
    Else
        MsgBox "The reference added successfully..."
    End If
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great work. Thank you for providing multiple options.

Comment: @Joemon Henry Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the answer is correct...

Comment: Just did it. I'm new to this platform and wasn't aware. 


In the 3rd option compile throws a "User-defined type not defined" for line


_Public Function getData_(path As String, fileName As String, Optional strCols As String = "") As ADODB.Recordset_


Need help on this.

Comment: @Joemon Henry The first line of the respective code is "**It needs a reference to 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library**". It needs that reference. Do you know how to install it? In fact, I will edit my answer and place a pice of code to automatically add it... Please, try the code I pasted and send some feedback.

Comment: After running the code I get the message   MsgBox **"The reference already exists..."**

Comment: When I run the entire code I still get _User-defined type not defined" for line Public Function getData_(path As String, fileName As String, Optional strCols As String = "") As ADODB.Recordset_

Comment: @Joemon Henry Do you use Windows as OS? If so and you have AnyDesk installed I can connect to your computer so see what's happening in your environment, if you allow such a connection. **"The reference already exists..."** appears in case of an error. Usually because the reference is already installed. Without seeing what's happening it is difficult to understand what error and why...